# Undetermined SIGABRT

Tags: c++

I'm at a loss here. I'm new to C/C++, moving from Java, so I'm not too knowledgable on the ins and outs of memory in C, which I think is the issue here.

The following is a class for a custom string, and a set of methods to determine anagrams of said string.

```
//Constructor
MyString::MyString(const char* input) {
    m_c = new char[strlen(input + 1)];
    strcpy(m_c, input);
}

bool MyString::IsAnagram(char* in) {
    int* a = BuildFreqTable(m_c);
    int* b = BuildFreqTable(in);
    if (strlen(m_c) != strlen(in))
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i<256; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;

int* MyString::BuildFreqTable(const char* s) {
    int* table = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        table[i] = 0;
    while (*s)
    {
        table[(unsigned char)*s]++;
        s++;
    }
    return table;
}
```

And in main I call the following:

```
            int strtptr = 0;
            getline(cin, cmd);
            MyString tmp = cmd.c_str();
            char* buf = new char[tmp.Length()];
            buf[0] = '\0';

            do
            {

                int endptr = tmp.IndexOf(",", strtptr);
                 if (endptr == -1) {
                    endptr = tmp.Length();
                    char* temp = (tmp.Substring(strtptr, endptr - strtptr).GetString());

                    if (data.IsAnagram(temp))
                        strcat(buf, temp);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    char* temp = (tmp.Substring(strtptr, endptr - strtptr).GetString());
                    if (data.IsAnagram(temp)) {
                        strcat(buf, temp);
                        strcat(buf, ",");
                    }
                    strtptr = endptr;
                    strtptr++;
                }
            } while (true);
            cout << buf;
        }
```

This works for singular input strings, but when some number of strings (unsure if number of characters or string delimiters), a SIGABRT comes up. The code for that is:

```
0x00007ffff7531cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: try changing this line `m_c = new char[strlen(input + 1)];` into `m_c = new char[strlen(input) + 1];`

Comment: That appears to have worked... what would be the reason for that?

Comment: `input + 1` increment the pointer `input` by one character. So you end up dropping the first character of the string. Your line was the equvalent of `m_c = new char[strlen(input) - 1];`. Your buffer was too small by the size of two character.